# Superclass mismatch in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, refactoring

I have a class:

```
class Example
  attr_reader :name
  ...
end
```

I later decided that I want to abstract out the `name` field into a parent class so it can be reused. When I load this code with `load 'filename.rb'`,

```
class Named
  attr_reader :name
  ...
end
class Example < Name
  ...
end
```

I get `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Example` because I'm trying to reopen the `Example` class and change its superclass, which is disallowed.

To get around this, I've been deleting the class manually by:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Example)
```

and then reloading, but this is cumbersome and annoying. Is there an easier way to force a reload without encountering this problem?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "abstract out the name field into a parent class ".

Comment: I wonder how your development process looks like, when you try to avoid reloading changed code...

Comment: Try to use mixin instead

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid reloading. I'm trying to eliminate the `Object.send(:remove_const, ...)` step.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo how do you reload your code? Do you have a long-running process that you modify at runtime?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I have irb running in the background and use `load 'main.rb'` to reload. I'm not sure if this is the most Ruby-ish way to do this, but I come from a Lisp background.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot change the parent of a class once it has been defined.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear. I don't want to change the parent. I want some way of telling Ruby that I'm not trying to modify the existing class but completely rebuild it from scratch so that I don't get that problem.